# jade is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to make a .cmd to compile my .jade files.
I am new to node.js and jade, jade was installed with

```
npm install jade --global
```

and the cmd i am trying to use is

```
jade jade --out ../MyApp
```

...which works when typed into the node.js command  prompt.

Comment: I think this is better for superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the jade.cmd and add it to my path. It was hidding at

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Now it's all working.

Comment: You seem to have found a solution by yourself. That is nice. Now you should consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution, and it will probably give you some points/reputation as well.